# Can I add custom pronunciations to "Speech"?

Tags: macos, customization, text-to-speech, voiceover

When given a well-known abbreviation or acronym, Mac's built-in Text-to-Speech engine automatically speaks the correct word or pronunciation, instead of the individual letters.

For example:

> vs
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "versus")
>
> Dec.
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "December")
>
> 5 cm
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "5 centimeters")
>
> Dr.
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "Doctor")
>
> Dept.
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "department")
>
> Rd
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "road")
>
> OPEC
>
> - (Speech pronunciation: "oh-peck")

However, there are instances where Speech does not pronounce a lesser-known abbreviation correctly, and, instead, speaks the individual letters of the word.

For example:

> BTW
>
> IMO
>
> YMMV

Is it possible to change the Speech behavior, so that when it is given "BTW," for example, it reads "by the way"?

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize the VoiceOver pronunciation for different words or abbreviations](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/voiceover/unac049/mac)

For instance, have "MR" pronounced as "merge request", but still leave "Mr"/"mr" pronounced as "mister":

[image]